# Tomcat 9.0.16 Java 11 HTTP/2

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, tls1.2, http2

Is TLS still a prerequisite for using HTTP/2 on the latest Java and Tomcat? Can I add `<UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol"/>` to HTTP port 8080 and expect HTTP/2 to work? How to actually test / see that HTTP/2 is actually being used instead of HTTP? Any command line / browswer tool? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the [HTTP Connector howto](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#HTTP/2_Support) states:

> HTTP/2 is support is provided for TLS (h2), non-TLS via HTTP upgrade
>   (h2c) and direct HTTP/2 (h2c) connections. To enable HTTP/2 support
>   for an HTTP connector the following **UpgradeProtocol** element must be
>   nested within the **Connector** with a **className** attribute of
>   `org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol`.

This suggests TLS is not a requirement. Question still is if your browser supports `h2c` upgrade.

Using Firefox, press (F12) to open the developer tools, navigate to **Networkanalysis**. There you see a table showing several attributes per request.
If not present, add the **Protocol** column which tells you whether HTTP/1, h2c or any other protocol is being used for each request.
Chrome also provides protocol information in a similar way:

Simply rightclick a column in the developer tools **Netowrk** section and you get an overview of all available columns:

[image]

**Another alternative** to debug protocol used by clients is **access logging**. Simply create a `context.xhtml` within the default `ROOT` webapp in `\apache-tomcat\webapps\ROOT\META-INF\` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"/>
</Context>
```

After restarting Tomcat and doing some requests you'll find a `\apache-tomcat\logs\localhost_access_log.2019-03-12.txt` which exactly states the protocol used for each request:

```
... - - [12/Mar/2019...] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11488
... - - [12/Mar/2019...] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11488
... - - [12/Mar/2019...] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 11468
```

In my case, both first requests where done using Chrome and Firefox, third request was done using the command `curl -v --http2 localhost:8080` you wrote in your other answer.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "Protocol" information in the Network tab of chrome debugger tool.

Comment: @KokHowTeh Did you try to add it? See the hint + figure in my edit.

Comment: Yes I see it now. However, as I do not configure HTTP/2 with TLS, I only see "h2" in the protocol window as apposed to h2c, which is then followed by http/2+quic/43... I am lost at this part as I thought I should expect to see h2c instead. What do I miss?

Comment: You can additionally click on a row in the Network view table and inspeckt the headers sent to and received from the server. Does it mention http/2 upgrade stuff? Using the command written by @KokHowTeh it does.

Comment: My Chrome btw. keeps on using protocol http/1.1 tho, how did you make your browser use http2?

Comment: @KokHowTeh just added a third protocol debugging alternative.

Comment: No, I don't see any http/2 upgrade stuff in the Network headers window. I did't do anything to the Chrome browser. Only add the UpgradeProtocol to server.xml and restart tomcat server.

Comment: Just to clarify. I see h2 and http/2+quic/43 when the server redirects to https and served from google sites. Others still use http/1.1 This is in line with the fact that Chrome only supports HTTP/2 with TLS.

Comment: What's that "quic/43" protocol?

Comment: I know QUIC is a new transport protocol. What's the "/43"? Port number? Protocol version?

Comment: From the search result linked above it looks like this is the version number.

Comment: Makes sense that the browsers aren't showing h2c, only h2. h2c makes most sense machine-to-machine on restricted subnets. An intended use case is between a proxy and a backend server. If you terminate TLS at the proxy, you can still use HTTP/2 to the backend with h2c. This is basically why browsers and servers differ on h2c support. As painful as it might be, I suggest to drop the browser testing of h2c from this answer, or edit to clearly explain its useful for h2 only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl -v --http2 localhost:8080` to check the actions after applying the UpgradeProtocol and restarting Tomcat server.